# Pandas date parsing return NaNs inside of .assign call

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataframe that I do a bunch of chain operations on in an `.assign` call and at the end I try to extract the month name to replace the full timestamp. Here is the code

```py
sub_df = (sub_df
 .resample('M', on='datetime')
 .sum()[['dur_vol', 'amount_aed']]
  .reset_index()
  .rename(columns={'dur_vol': 'dur_vol_sum', 'amount_aed': 'amount_aed_sum'})
  .assign(
       datetime=sub_df['datetime'].dt.month_name()
   )
 )
```

Up until the `rename` the dataframe looks like this
[image]

Everything works as expected except that the `assign` method returns the `datetime` series full of NaNs. When I take it out of the chain operation and execute it after it returns the month names normally. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of the input `sub_df`

Comment: You've changed your index; the `sub_df` index probably no longer aligns with your resampled index.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callable (e.g. a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#lambda-expressions)), you can also replace `rename` with [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), and slice before `sum` to avoid computing the result for the dropped columns:

```
sub_df = (sub_df
 .resample('M', on='datetime')
 [['dur_vol', 'amount_aed']].sum()
 .add_suffix('_sum')
 .reset_index()
 .assign(datetime=lambda d: d['datetime'].dt.month_name())
)
```

##### Why do we need a callable?

If you reference `sub_df` in `assign`, this will take the value of `sub_df` before any of the chained operations. A callable enables to reference the DataFrame in the current state.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})

out = (df
   .mul(10)
   .assign(B=df['A'],         # reference original df
           C=lambda d: d['A'] # reference current state
          )
)
```

Output:

```
    A  B   C
0  10  1  10
1  20  2  20
2  30  3  30
```

In your case, I imagine that "datetime" was originally a column, then the index of your DataFrame changed because of the `resample`+`reset_index` operations, which causes `.assign(datetime=sub_df['datetime'].dt.month_name())` to fail because of index alignment but without any error as the column indeed existed in the original `sub_df`.

Comment: Thank you for that info! Can you please explain what was going wrong and why did the `lambda` fix it?

Comment: @KareemAmr I updated the answer with an explanation